# pg_restore: [directory archiver] could not open input file. Error while trying to restore DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, navicat

Error when trying to restore a backup file(.nb3).

I did a database backups in Navicat, one backup for each schema. They are .nb3 files. 
I tried to restore my DB on a local server using pgAdmin. I got an error like this after choosing backup file :
[image]

How do I restore the database on a local server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB3 NaviCat backup files can be restored using the NaviCat software.

1. Add the database connection in NaviCat
2. Double click on the connection and go to Backup
3. Right-click on the empty backup window and select "Restore from..." from the menu
4. Select your nb3 file